# Quickest manual way to check what version of the Windows Installer is installed?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-installer

I have a production server and need to know what version of the windows installer is running, what's a quick way to find this out without running the 4.5 installer on the server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a command prompt:

```
msiexec /?
```

It displays the version on the first line. EG: Windows ® Installer. V 3.01.4000.1823

Comment: Brilliant! thankyou  SCORE: ServerFault:1 Google/Bing:0

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the version of MSI.dll.

=== EDIT: For some reason I read this as you needing to do this in a scriptable way. msiexec /? is of course a faster way to do it if you just need to check it manually. ===

You can do this with VBScript.

Create a file like this called VersionInfo.vbs:

```
set args = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.GetFileVersion(args(0))
Wscript.Quit
```

Then call it like:

```
cscript //nologo VersionInfo.vbs %windir%\system32\msi.dll
```

NOTE: the script was pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602802/command-line-tool-to-dump-windows-dll-version).

Comment: You're better off just doing this in a VBS: set installer = createobject("windowsinstaller.installer") 
msgbox installer.version

Comment: @Izzy: thx. I guess if you are incorporating it into a script, you would just do wscript.echo installer.version at the end.

Comment: if it was scripting i would have asked on stackoverflow, good to know if i ever need to do a mass deployment :)

Answer (score 2):

- Check the version of MSI.DLL (%windir%\System32)
- OR run the following: msiexec /?

Or, if you want to get clever, make a .VBS file, paste the following into it, and double click it:

```
set installer = createobject("windowsinstaller.installer") 
msgbox installer.version
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the information using Powershell:

get-item $env:windir\system32\msi.dll | fl

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Answer (score -3):

for the shortest way of check; just after clicking start menu, choose run box and type msiexec there , then it will popup a window of windows installer with instructions and the version number in the heading...

Comment: How is this any better than the accepted answer?